# Using Amazon TVM instead of a regular AccessKey/SecretKey

Tags: android, security, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am building an Android application that will send reports to a server. These reports are plain JSON files stored on Amazon S3.
The Amazon user only has the PutObject permission on a specific S3 bucket.

The [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/gsg/) states that we should use the Token Vending Machine mechanism instead of hardcoded keys within the application.

I cannot see the advantage of this method. 
I get that a hacker could decompile my app to find the keys. But his only choice then is to send files to the bucket, nothing else (no file listing, no file retrieval).

If I use the anonymous TVM, the process is:

- Get a token valid for 24 hours
- Use this token to send files to the bucket

A hacker could also call the TVM server to request unlimited tokens and send files to my bucket. It does not seem to solve this problem.

What is the real advantage in using TVM?

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762729/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-using-aws-specifically-s3-from-mobile-apps/22769259#22769259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach different authorizations to each mobile UID, giving your finer control over what you allow people to access. You can also control how much AWS access the TVM has using policies. You can also stop it any given time. If they get your keys, you will have to disable the whole account. If you are OK with that, you probably don't need to use the TVM.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. I think what you say does not apply to my use case. I am OK to revoke the account and force users to update (for this specific app, that's fine)

Comment: It also appears that you can now create keys at a user level & assign policies to that user, e.g. putObject to S3. Which to me seems to make using TVM less favourable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: So the TVM should check the UID and verify the user? How can i make sure that the credentials are given only to the application.